# The entire area inside div is not linked

Tags: css, html

I got two divs, and ive given the divs backgrounds.

They have exactly the same attributes/css.. But one div is fully clickable (the entire image inside the div area is clickable), the other one is only clickable here and there.. Any ideas?

http://romeon.net/deffrage

Its the two buttons

"Deffrage" "Josef"

its the deffrage button that is not working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.backlava` item is obstructing the link below it. You'll need to adjust the dimensions of this item. You might be able to simply remove the explicitly-declared `height` from the `li`. A quick test revealed that this fixed the problem, without affecting the layout (you should test further though if you decide to go that route).

[image]

Comment: Dude, you are my hero. Honly mother of mary, i've been trying to find the solution for months, asked all swedish developers I knew, and posted on forums.. You found it in a few sec? :S

Answer (score 0):

In following code, change height from 53 to 3.

```
<li class="backLava" style="left: 9px; top: 0px; width: 66px; height: 53px; overflow: hidden;"><div class="leftLava"></div><div class="bottomLava"></div><div class="cornerLava"></div></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both link for me. But one of them has the end tags in the wrong order (`</span></div></a>` where it should have been `</a></span></div>`).

And this CSS

```
.robin {position: relative;float: left;margin-right: 100px;}
```

applies to only one of them.

(And what's the point of the span without either a class or an id? That's a no-op, I'd say).

Comment: You could do css selections to the span from a parent element with a class or an id. Like .myDiv span { font-weight: bold; } so that the html is a bit cleaner. Just a thought though.

Comment: @MatthewKruskamp: Yeah, but that does not actually seem to be happening here.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be Javascript setting the height of the backlava class to 53px instead of it's default of 16px. Remove whatever Javascript is doing that and you should be good.